# Syntax highlighting is not consistent

Tags: discussion, design

Stack Exchange says for syntax highlighting, the highlighting will be inferred from the tags or can be specified with a languge directive (e.g., lang-py).

However, I just edited a post at [Python ctypes: how to use pointer passed to DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48070278/python-ctypes-how-to-use-pointer-passed-to-dll) and some of the code lines are highlighted and the latest code lines in the edit are not highlighted.  I placed a language directive at the top, but that did not change it.

My question is why are the most recent code lines not highlighted and the others are?  No other formatting tags appear in the text.

Answer (score -3):

For Python, the answer is that the lines must be indented four spaces.  Then they will be picked up as code lines.

Comment: That's not specific to Python, it's just how code formatting works on Stack Overflow.